# ¿Cómo puedo ver (u obtener) el código fuente de algún comando de GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, script, línea-de-comandos

Alguien sabra donde o como puedo ver el código fuente de cualquier comando de GNU/Linux por ejemplo cd, ls, mkdir y etc.
¿Existira alguna libraria de linux que las contenga? 
¿Cual seria esta librería? 
¿O saber si realmente no es posible, por motivos a que es código cerrado? -> aun que no lo creo ya que GNU/Linux es Open Source.

Comment: Intenta con esto: http://www.linuxhispano.net/2010/02/23/howto-obtener-el-codigo-fuente-de-cualquier-aplicacion-comando-en-linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Definitivamente no es código cerrado. Todos los comandos básicos son parte del paquete `coreutils`.

La información que necesitas [está aquí](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). Si quieres la última versión del código fuente, te recomiendo que utices [`git`](https://git-scm.com):

```
> git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils
```

Para instalar `git`, asumiendo que estás en UBUNTU/DEBIAN puedes hacer:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Asumiendo que estás en RedHat/CentOS/Fedora:

```
yum install git
```

Ejemplo, [acá tienes en formato HTML el código de `ls`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c). Casi 5000 línes de código para un comando tan sencillo como `ls`. :-)

Buena suerte!